# Show that $1/(1+\|A\|) < \|(I-A)^{-1}\| <1/(1-\|A\|)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

> If $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix such that $\|A\|<1$,
>   show that $(I-A)$ is invertible and 
>   $$
> \frac{1}{1+\|A\|}  < \|(I-A)^{-1}\| <\frac{1}{1-\|A\|}
> $$

My trial:

First  to show $I-A$ is invertible:
if not, then there exists nonzero vector $x$ such that 
$(I-A)x =0 $
Hence 
$Ax=x$
So $\|x\|=\|Ax\|\le\|A\| \|x\|$ and since $x$ is a non zero vector we get $\|A\|\ge\|x\|$ which contradicts the assumption.

To prove the second part, by the triangle inequality we have
$$
\|I\|-\|A\| \le \|I-A\|\le\|I\|+\|A\|
$$
But the norm of the identity is equal to 1.

I stopped here since I know $\|(I-A)^{-1}\|$ doesn't equal $\|I-A\|^{-1}$

Any help?

*The norm here is the spectral norm or the operator norm.*

Comment: The first part may be the same, but I believe the second part is different enough to merit its own post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $(I-A)^{-1}=I+(I-A)^{-1}A$, $$\|(I-A)^{-1}\|\leq 1+\|(I-A)^{-1}\|\|A\|,$$ which gives the upper bound. From $(I-A)^{-1}(I-A)=I$, we have $$1\leq\|(I-A)^{-1}\|\|I-A\|\leq\|(I-A)^{-1}\|(1+\|A\|),$$ which gives the lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

Consider matrix $B=I+A+A^2+A^3+\ldots$ (prove that the series converges) and calculate the product $B(I-A)$. Then estimate the norm of $B$.

Comment: So here B to converges to the inverse, and then we can use the submultiplicative property and  estimate the result by geometric series ,,thanks for your help :)